# Merging Map of LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two Map of LinkedHashMap in this format==> `Map<String,LinkedHashMap<String,String>>` both m1 & m2 have same key values, How we combine this m1 & m2 and make m3 with all elements.
 **Note :Can you some one give psuedocode I will implement it.Thanks.**

Input is like below format:

```
m1={1={rollno=1,name=chris,height=7ft},2={rollno=2,name=stephen,height=6ft}}
m2={1={rollno=1,name=chris,weight=65},2={rollno=2,name=stephen,weight=73}}
```

Output :

```
     m3={1={rollno=1,name=chris,height=7ft,weight=65},2={rollno=2,name=stephen,height=6ft,weight=73}}
```

What I tried :

```
private static Map<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>>  mergeMap(Map<String,LinkedHashMap<String, String>> m1, Map<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>> m2) { 

    Map<String,LinkedHashMap<String, String>> newMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>>(m1);
    for (Map.Entry<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>> entry : m2.entrySet()) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> t1=newMap.get(entry.getKey());
        newMap.putAll(m2);
    }

    System.out.println("ouput :"+newMap);
    return newMap;
}
```

Comment: So the size of both map should be same?

Comment: yes both size are similar

Comment: You should do - `t1.putAll(entry.getValue())`. Or simply - `newMap.get(entry.getKey()).putAll(entry.getValue());`

Comment: Thanks it works as expected .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the steps below to merge the maps:

1. First create a newMap, passing first map - `map1` as parameter. You have to use the overloaded constructor - [`LinkedHashMap(Map)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#LinkedHashMap%28java.util.Map%29) for that. Now you have a map with all the elements of `map1`. Half of your job is done.

   ```
   Map<String, Map<String, String>> newMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(map1);
   ```
2. Then you need to move elements from 2nd map to the newMap. For that, you would need to iterate over `map2`. You can use [`Map#entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) method to iterate over each entry in `map2`. You would then use [`Map.Entry#getKey()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getKey%28%29) and [`Map.Entry#getValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getValue%28%29) methods to get the key and value respectively for each entry.

   - For each key in `map2`, get the current value from `newMap`, and merge the value of `map2`, with the value in `newMap`. Both the values are `Map`. You can use [`Map#putAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29) method to merge the two maps. It will automatically ignore the already available keys, and add the extra key-value pair.

---

Now, after resolving the above issue, you should consider changing your data structure. You should create a class say `Person`, to store all those attributes, and maintain a `Map<Integer, Person>`, where key will be `rollNo`.

What you have shown is just what you have. If you could explain some other details like, how and from where did you get those maps, and why would you possibly have the attributes of same person distributed in two different maps, may be we can help you better to formulate the data structure properly. Having a nested Map might be handled if you have small set of data, but if you have larger set of data, you will face difficult in handling them. You should certainly follow Object Oriented Approach.

Comment: Thanks rohit I will implement it now. I have a doubt **You have to use the overloaded constructor - LinkedHashMap(Map) for that** what it exactly means.can you give example for that ?

Comment: @BALASCJP. Yeah. Tell me?

Answer (score 0):

You should use java object to store complete information.

like

```
class Student{
   int rollNo; 
   String name;
   String height;
   String weight;
}
```

And store your elements like

```
Map<Integer,Student> map = new HashMap<Integer,Student>();
```

it will be much easy to merge and store and manage element like this

Comment: 1) This doesn't answer the question. 2) I would argue this would make the values easier to merge; quite on the contrary...

Comment: Please explain why this approach is not easier compare to storing key value pair..... Roll number(Integer) will be the key and we can compare and merge easily.

Comment: As a general design recommendation, I agree with you. However, in this particular case the question is related to merging maps; moreover `m1.putAll(m2)` is less complex than writing a `Sudent.merge(Student other)` (or some utility `merge(Student s1, Student s2)`) method where you would check each individual property or use reflection.